# How to find/replace a character in every specific line

Tags: notepad++, emeditor

assume i have 500,000 line ends with comma (,) like this:

```
test,'number',null,
test,'number',null,
test,'number',null,
```

i want to find/replace comma (,) with (;) in the end of for example every 50,000 line:

```
line 1:      test,'number',null,
line 50:     test,'number',null,
line 50,000: test,'number',null;
```

is that possible to do with nodepad++ or emeditor?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **EmEditor**, you can run this macro while your 500,000 line document is active. To do this, save this code as, for instance, `ReplaceEvery50000.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, open your 500,000 line document, and select **Run** in the **Macros** menu while your 500,000 line document is active.

```
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4472);  // ensure non-CSV mode
yLines = document.GetLines();
for( y = 50000; y <= yLines; y += 50000 ) {
    s = document.GetLine( y );
    x = s.length;
    if( s.substr( x - 1, 1 ) == "," ) {
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, x, y );
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, x + 1, y, true );
        document.selection.Text = ";";
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked just fine, thanks dude. where have you been till now :D

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^\r\n]*,\R){49999}[^\r\n]+\K,$`
- Replace with: `;`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (?:               # non capture group
    [^\r\n]*        # 0 or more any character but newline
    ,               # a comma
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
  ){49999}          # end group, must appear 49999 times
  [^\r\n]+          # 1 or more non linebreak
  \K                # reset
  ,                 # a comma
$                   # end of line
```

I've `3` lines instead of `50000` for example.

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: it works for nodepad++ but not working in emeditor, what about that? cause i have a large file

Comment: @Michael: I don't know emeditor, may be it doesn't support `\K`, you can try with: Find: `^((?:[^\r\n]*,\R){49999}[^\r\n]+),$` Replace: `$1;` or `\1;`

Comment: didn't work in emeditor, can you try it on that because i have a big sql and i cant open it in nodepad++, also i have tried in nodepad++ {49999} is not working only under 15000 like {14300} works.

Comment: @Michael: A perl oneliner does the job: `perl -pe 's/,$/;/ unless $.%50000' inputfile`. Make a backup before!

Comment: In **EmEditor**, click the **Advanced** button in the **Replace** dialog box, and enter `50000` in the **Additional Lines to Search for Regular Expressions** text box.